# How to compress any picture?

Tags: java, image, io, compression

Our site have a posibility to load user pictures. User can load absolutely any file(we believe that it will a picture at the moment). On page we show a lot of pictures thus we have a huge internet traffic. we want to compress pictures on server. I have found following article about picture compressing.

[How to compress jpg file?](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_dip/image_compression_technique.htm)

But there are explained how to compress concrete format. Is there universal way for compressing any picture?

Comment: no, there isn't. there are several different ways to compress images. the big distinction are lossy and lossless methods.

Comment: maybe should we convert format of input picture to single selected?

Comment: if CPU is not a problem, you can just try to use several methods to compress the same image and keep the one that results in a smaller image.

Comment: What about https://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/ or https://github.com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr

Answer (score 0):

A picture is a very broad term that could also include vector graphics, pictures that are in a format that browsers usually can't display (like psd files).

I would recommend to use the gd lib or imagemagick on the server side to convert them all (or at least these that are supported by your choice) to a standarized format (like jpg) that can be displayed in a webbrowser and get compressed (maybe also resized).

100% of possible image files a user could upload can't be converted afaik.